# Jquery-easyui combobox, how to get textfield when submit form

Tags: jquery-easyui

I have a `combobox` element from `jquery-easyui`:

```html
<form name="myform" method="post"><input id="city" 
       class="easyui-combobox" 
       data-option="valuefield:'id_city', Textfield:'name_city', Url:'getcity.php', method:'get'"/> </form>
```

When `myform` submits
I'm using `$_Post['city']` to get a valuefield and it works.
But how to get a `textfield` using same method?

Comment: up...please somebody help me

Comment: nobody can't answer this?  omg..............lol

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to retrieve the text from the combobox, set the 'valueField' and 'textField' with the same value. Or you can use the following method:

```
    `$('#city').combobox('getText');`
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

getText does not return the text in the input field if it is typed manually. It only works if the tree was used to select the text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center.